# Compiling SDL-based app in Xcode 5 fails, 'SDL.h' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, xcode5

Today I came across a copy of [SAIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Adventures_in_Infinite_Space) that has been mouldering on my HD for some time, and found that it no longer works - PPC target! I downloaded the source, which is C++ that uses SDL to build a Windows binary. SDL should make it somewhat portable...

Under Xcode 5.1.1 I made a new Command Line Tool application and selected C++ as the language. Then I copied all the source over to the new project, along with the `SDL2.framework` that I downloaded.

Then I made a target for my machine. I went to my Build Phases and added `SDL2.framework` to the Link Binary With Libraries step, and added it to the Copy Files step as well. I then added the header folder inside the framework to my Header Search Path.

Did I miss anything here? Because when I build I get `'SDL.h' file not found`. Yes, that file *is* in the framework.

Comment: What does the the `#include` line look like that triggers the error

Comment: Good question! It is `#include <SDL.h>`. I also tried `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`

Comment: Probably the include path you tell xcode should be relative to this. So if the line is `#include <SDL.h>` and your SDL.h is at `/usr/foo/SDL.h` then `/usr/foo` should be added to your header search configuration

Comment: I have this: `"$(SRCROOT)/SDL2.framework/Headers"` The framework is in the source folder.

Comment: So did you add that path to the header search path? Does `SRCROOT/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL.h` exist?

Comment: Yes, in the paths, yes, file exists.

Comment: I haven't gotten intimate with xcode before but no matter the build system, if I write "#include <foo.h>" and then I put the path to foo.h in my search path, then whatever build system you are using should be able to find that file. If that doesn't work then something is seriously wrong.

Comment: It suddenly started working yesterday night, I have no idea what I changed. :-(